# how to use an image stored in internal data storage in android

Tags: android, imagedownload

In my app when the splash screen gets started I am downloading an image from the URL. I want to use the same image in another activity of my app. Following is my code to download the image

```
public void DownloadImage(String fileName)      
    {

        try 
        {
                           URL url = new URL(main.BannerImage); //you can write here any link                          
                           File file = new File(fileName);
                           Log.e("file ",""+file);

                           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();                          
                           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();                         
                           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                           ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                           int current = 0;
                           while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
                           {
                                 baf.append((byte) current);
                           }

                           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                           fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                           fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
                            Log.e("Error: ","" + e);
        }
```

How can I get the image as a background source in another activity please help me friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the image in SDCard and the path can be send to next activity using

```
intent.putExtras("filename","filepathname");
```

and get in the next activity using

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("filename")
```

from this you can get filepath from previous activity and you can get the image from specific filepath.

You can convert the image into bitmap and and pass it to next activity using Parcelable like

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
extras.putParcelable("data",bitmap);
Intent intent=new Intent(currentActivity.this,nextImage.class); 
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

in nextactivity you can get bitmap as

```
 Bitmap  image=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("data");
```